# What's wrong with my Planck law implementation?

Tags: c++, physics

Maybe I'm just overtired, but I can't see why this simple code to calculate Planck's law isn't working.

[image]

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

const double h = 6.626070040e-34;

const double c = 299792458;

const double kB = 1.38064852e-23;

double planck_law_wavelength (double t, double l)
{
    return ((2 * h * c * c) / (l * l * l * l * l))
        / (exp (h * c / (l * t * kB)) - 1);
}

int main ()
{
    std::cout << planck_law_wavelength (4000, 0.5e-6) << std::endl;
}
```

This outputs `2.86509e+12` but according to the diagram below I should be getting values on the order of 3000 candela, not this tiny number.

[image]

Where is the mistake?

Comment: I do have some knowledge in physics, and all, but you do miss the `return` in your `main` function. Sorry for nitpicking :) Good question though.

Comment: try to use `long double` instead of `double`

Comment: @AndrejsCainikovs `main()` is the one non-void function where the return can be omitted. It has an implicit `return 0`.

Comment: @IlyaBursov that doesn't change.

Comment: Probably numerical error.

Comment: Instead of one single big expr try to calculate and print also intermediate results from within plank_law_w()

Comment: Make sure your constants are correct. Additionally, `double` only has about `16` decimal places (52 bits) for the mantissa in 64-bit implementations. So you might have to scale your inputs accordingly.

Comment: you are answer is correct! this [Online Plunk  Calculator](https://www.fxsolver.com/solve/) gives the answer 2.86509646449e+12 too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your result is correct, the y-axis in graph below is in `nm`, `kW`. If you transform those to SI unit, there is a factor of `1e12`. Roughly `3e12` according to the graph, very close to your computed result.

Comment: I noticed the scales already. My argument is `0.5e-6` i.e. 0.5 nm. And isn't the Planck formula already in SI units? As in, Watts on the y-axis? So I'd expect my output to be about 3,000 to agree with the graph.

Comment: No. The y-axis has *nm^(-1)*, this one is *not* SI unit, there is a difference of `1e9`. You only noticed the x-axis, not the y.

Answer (score 0):

The graph is just using a different scale.  Bλ units are W·sr−1·m−3.